# Select SQL data in php and sort

Tags: html, database, web, auto-generate

Hi guys new to PHP and mySQL and have a question regarding how to display SQL records within a web page, ideally it would be displayed in a box where a scroll bar could be used to sort through the records.

It would be perfect if the fields could be displayed like; |ID|John|Shoes| for example.

Any advice on how to make this happen is greatly appreciated.
If anyone could advise on how to generate an incremental onvoice number like #001>#002 that would be a bonus.

Comment: Can you show what you tried, the code?

Comment: google your question. This sounds like and assignment project

Comment: I only have basic to bring SQL data back in simple cell tabled form, as stated above I need this in a list manner which can be sorted through. There is no code for me to suggest because this is something i never approached before.